# Javascript get url if match

Tags: javascript, url

I have a code here but always result to "**alert(2)**". Help me correct my code on url matching using regex global

```
var curl = document.URL;
var burl = document.location;
var ctitle = document.title;
var url = /"catalogsearch\/advanced"/g;

if(curl.match(url) == true) {
    alert(1);
} else {
    alert(2);
}
```

Comment: Can you try: var url = /catalogsearch\/advanced/g;

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from the regexp and use the regexp test method:

```
var curl = document.URL;
var burl = document.location;
var ctitle = document.title;
var url = /catalogsearch\/advanced/g;

if(url.test(curl)) {
    alert(1);
} else {
    alert(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression you could try this:

```
if(curl.indexOf("catalogsearch/advanced") != -1) {
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ""

```
document.URL.match(/questions\/5328532/);
```

works fine